# QR code scanning in blackberry os 7.1

Tags: blackberry

I am developing an qr code scanning application in blackberry. I am using ZXing library for scanning.Scanning and everything working properly.

But when I am using device having os 7.1, I am getting black/white screen instead of color screen in scanning screen. While opening the app it showing color screen but suddenly after one second it giving me black/white screen.

Does anyone face this issue earlier? How to fix it?

Comment: check this http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/How-to-use-the-Barcode-API/ta-p/574569     and    http://aliirawan-wen.blogspot.in/2011/05/barcode-scanner-for-blackberry-os-50.html

Comment: Scanning is perfectly working for me.the only issue is the camera showing black and white screen instead of color screen in os 7.1.

Comment: @user59 - are you using the built-in zxing library?

Comment: Yes Peter.I am using the built-in zxing library since it is os 7